# Use attributes in a tfvars file

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a file fsx.tf with 2 resource blocks and a file prod.tfvars:

**My fsx.tf looks like:**

```
resource "aws_fsx_ontap_storage_virtual_machine" "fsx_svm" {
  for_each                       = var.fsx_svm
  file_system_id                 = aws_fsx_ontap_file_system.fsx.id
  name                           = each.value.name
}

resource "aws_fsx_ontap_volume" "fsx_volumes" {
  for_each                    = var.fsx_volumes
  name                        = var.name
  storage_virtual_machine_id  = each.value.storage_virtual_machine_id
```

**My prod.tfvars looks like:**

```
fsx_svm = {
          svm01 = {
           name = "svm01-single-az"
           }
}
        
fsx_volumes = {
           vol01 = {
           name  = "FS"
          storage_virtual_machine_id  = fsx_svm.svm01.id
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

> Error: expected length of storage_virtual_machine_id to be in the range (21 - 21), got fsx_svm.svm01.id

OR

> Variables not allowed here

How to set the attribute id of resource aws_fsx_ontap_storage_virtual_machine in the variable of fsx_volumes ? My goal is to be able to reuse the resource block for other .tfvars files.

Comment: That cannot be done. But you can use local variables instead.

Comment: @MarkoE: Thanks so instead of using the variables fsx_svm and fsx_volumes, I have to use locals ? After that, how to set the attribute id in local.fsx_volumes ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand completely what the goal is. Should there be a connection between the two resources?

Comment: In resource block aws_fsx_ontap_volume, for the argument storage_virtual_machine_id, if I want to make it work, I have to set the argument to: aws_fsx_ontap_storage_virtual_machine.fsx_svm["svm01"].id so here it will work. But if I do that, I will have to duplicate the block aws_fsx_ontap_volume for each key of var fsx_svm

Comment: Ok, so this is the argument you want to have dynamically set: `storage_virtual_machine_id`?

Comment: Yes I want to set the argument storage_virtual_machine_id (this value is the attribute id of  resource aws_fsx_ontap_storage_virtual_machine.fsx_svm

Answer (score 2):

In this case the best way to do this may be resource chaining with `for_each` [1]. This means instead of having to rely on variables you can just do this:

```
resource "aws_fsx_ontap_storage_virtual_machine" "fsx_svm" {
  for_each                       = var.fsx_svm
  file_system_id                 = aws_fsx_ontap_file_system.fsx.id
  name                           = each.value.name
}

resource "aws_fsx_ontap_volume" "fsx_volumes" {
  for_each                    = aws_fsx_ontap_storage_virtual_machine.fsx_svm
  name                        = "${each.key}-${var.name}"
  storage_virtual_machine_id  = each.value.id
}
```

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each#chaining-for_each-between-resources

Comment: Thanks, I am trying this solution. And all arguments of resource block aws_fsx_ontap_volume.fsx_volumes have to be declared as variable (for example var.name for the name argument) ?

Comment: Well, they don't,  you need different names right?

Comment: Yes, my question is: if I need to create multiples volumes (vol02, vol03, vol04...) with different names . How I would proceed ?

Comment: I just updated the answer, does that work for you?

Comment: Great, thanks! Sorry, last question, how my tfvars file can be written for all the arguments of resource block aws_fsx_ontap_volume ? Before the change, it was easy because I had the for_each = var.fsx_volumes and I just needed to duplicate vol01 to vol02 and vol03 and so on in my tfvars

Comment: I have other arguments that are specific to resource block aws_fsx_ontap_volume, not sure how I have to set them

Comment: Well, I would say those are all different questions compared to the OP. Regarding the other arguments, the question showed only three, so that's why my answer has only three. If you add all the arguments, then I could probably give an assumption as I am not really familiar with FSx.